# How to install SQLPLUS (Oracle DB API) on Windows 2008

Tags: sqlplus

I am googling on this subject for many hours but have not been able to resolve this simple question.

I want to install ONLY the sqlplus and oci client on my windows machine. The oracle server is running remotely. On this windows box I only want the client components including sqlplus terminal.

I have already done the following on my windows machine

download oracle data access components from here

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

run cmd.exe as administrator and Run the following command

install all c:\oracle myhome

In windows control panel set the following environment variables

```
ORACLE_HOME=C:\ORACLE
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\ORACLE
LIB_PATH=c:\ORACLE
NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
PATH=C:\ORACLE;C:\ORACLE\BIN
```

But when I run sqlplus.exe I get an error

****SP2-0667: Message file sp1.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory****

All my searches are showing me that people solve this by setting oracle_home correctly... but I think they install the full server product whereas I have only installed the client components using the command listed above.

What am I missing? how can I get a working sqlplus without installing the full server on my machine?

Comment: I have solved the problem. For benefit of others I am documenting the steps which I took to make it work.

1. deleted everything and download fresh 2 zip files (basic and sqlplus) from oracle otn
2. unzip in c:\oracle\isntantclient_11_2
3. set ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\isntantclient_11_2
4. SET TNS_ADMIN=c:\oracle\isntantclient_11_2
5. SET PATH=c:\oracle\isntantclient_11_2;%PATH%
6. REBOOTED MY MACHINE